# How to print a file's contents backwards?

Tags: java, file

I have an assignment where I need to read a file's contents in reverse, like this:

Original:

```
This is how you reverse a file, 10
```

New:

```
10 ,file a reverse you how is This
```

Here's the code I have:

```
public static void main(String [args]{
    Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Java\\Sample.txt");
    InputStream input = null;
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
    input = Files.newInputStream(files);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    String s;
    while((s = reader.readLine()) != null)
        words.add(s);
    for(int i = words.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            System.out.print(words.get(i));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Sorry if the formatting is off.  The program simply reads the file in original form.  What am I doing wrong?  Can anyone explain what I need to have this print backwards?  My textbook doesn't explain anything.
Also, I realize that my catch block is possibly too broad.  I'll work on that.

EDIT: I forgot to add the ArrayList code when typing this out.  It exists already in my original program.

Thank you

Comment: Should that be `file,` in the output rather than `,file`?

Comment: What happens if the file has multiple lines - is each line printed backwards one at a time or the last one is printed backwards first followed by the next one?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your program.

Comment: Yes, it should be file, in the output.  Each line is printed backwards one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

```
while((s = reader.readLine()) != null)
    words.add(s);
```

The second line implies that `s` holds words, but the first line reads a line at a time. You need to read a word at a time, or [split the lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) into words.

Comment: @Nikki since you are obviously new to Java, I'll give you the method for splitting the lines: `words.addAll(Arrays.asList(s.split("[\\s]")));`

Comment: All is contingent on `words` having been declared as a `List<String>` somewhere in code we _haven't_ been shown...

Comment: I edited my post to include the ArrayList.  I overlooked it when typing up my post.  I appreciate the feedback and for being provided the method.  Indeed, I'm very new to Java.